# Por que a última previsão da série temporal com o pacote neuralnet é muito discrepante ao resto das previsões?

Tags: r, redes-neurais

Eu ajustei uma rede neural pra fazer previsão de precipitação sazonal a partir da séries observadas. Quando faço a validação com dados observados, os resultados são bons. Mas na série prevista pelo modelo, a última previsão é sempre com valores muito abaixo do normal. Chega a dar seca para locais de precipitação contínua. Como esse modelo ta sendo construído para ser operacionalizado, o último número da série prevista é o mais importante, pois é a previsão que faremos todos os meses.

Alguém sabe o por que desse viés negativo somente para o último número? Sabem como resolver?

E tentei usar outros pacotes como o rnn, que é de rede neural recorrente. Porém, os resultados não são tão bons. Acredito que seja pelo fato de pouco treino. Mas é uma rede que demora demais pra treinar. Um treino de 2000 interações demorou 9 horas e deu resultado ruim. Como o modelo tem que prever para todo o Brasil, o treino de mais de 250 séries duraria meses.

Outro detalhe importante é que a série alimento o modelo é de acumulados trimestrais. Por exemplo, operacionalmente quando queremos fazer previsão para o acumulado de Dezembro-Janeiro-Fevereiro, não temos a média mensal de Novembro. Então as duas última observações que alimenta o modelo é um acumulado entre o último mês observado (Outubro) e a climatologia dos dois próximos (Novembro e Dezembro). Isso demanda uma abordagem diferente para ajuste do modelo. O que faz com que certos pacotes de previsão de série temporal não sejam úteis. Por que não me permitem controlar as variáveis de entrada. Só permitem que eu coloque uma  série e ele faz tudo.

Espero que possam me ajudar. Estou desesperado. É meu TCC e precisa dar certo. Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: As séries utilizadas para treinar o modelo tem quantas observações? A previsão que está sendo realizada para quantos passos à frente? Tu chegou a fazer um gráfico comparando o comportamento dos valores observados com o comportamento dos valores previstos, sem olhar apenas para os dados numéricos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu vou dar uma resposta que você não vai gostar.

Usar redes neurais para prever o tempo é um **negócio traiçoeiro**. Não quer dizer que seja impossível - apenas quer dizer que é trabalhoso.

As redes neurais são ótimas para separar padrões. Se os seus dados sobre o clima no passado recente forem linearmente separáveis, a rede vai convergir para uma estrutura na qual será capaz de dar chutes sobre se vai chover ou não. Até aqui tudo bem, certo?

O problema é: se redes neurais fossem seres humanos, elas seriam os piores alunos da sala em qualquer escola. De todos os tipos de inteligência artificial que eu conheço, elas são o paradigma que menos busca entender como as coisas funcionam. Elas só querem saber as respostas, sem se importar muito como chegam a elas. Pra piorar, ainda tem o fator decoreba que muitas delas apresentam - depois que aprendem errado, pode ficar difícil corrigí-las e fazer com que aprendam certo.

Caso anedotal: [o pentágono gastou milhões de dólares no desenvolvimento de uma rede neural que fosse capaz de identificar tanques de guerra em fotos, mas ao invés disso conseguiram uma rede neural que só sabia distinguir céu limpo de céu nublado](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/tank/).

---

No seu caso, você informou à sua rede dados que devem incluir velocidade do vento, precipitação, temperatura, pressão e humidade do ar, frentes frias, frentes quentes, poluição atmosférica, época do ano etc. para a sua rede, e ela até consegue dar alguma informação útil para a maioria dos casos. Aí você pensa que ela aprendeu a interpretar o input... Mas será que aprendeu mesmo a interpretar os dados com os quais você a alimenta? Ou será que ela só decorou a resposta certa para cada input?

---

Por fim... A tarefa a qual você se propôs não é impossível. Mas você vai ter que fazer muito mais do que já fez até agora para chegar onde quer.

Se você fizer uma pesquisa, vai encontrar uns cinco mil artigos sobre previsão de tempo com redes neurais publicados só este ano. Você precisa ver o que esses caras fizeram e implementar do mesmo jeito. Pode ser - ênfase em **pode** - que você tenha que descartar os pacotes que está utilizando, e fazer a sua própria implementação de redes neurais. Porém, só a criação de uma rede neural em si, nesse nível de complexidade, já poderia valer um TCC em si, então talvez seja o momento de repensar o seu tema.